# Why does my Wikipedia crawler fail when using CachedThreadPool but not when using FixedThreadPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, url, concurrency, synchronized

I wrote a little Java program that allows me to track the life status of famous people, notifying me when someone on my "watch list" dies. I used Wikipedia's APIs to fetch the data, which is then processed using custom methods. I know there are much better ways to crawl Wikipedia but I wanted to practice my Java as I hadn't touched it in a while.

For now, I can add new people, save them to a local "database" and view the list of people I've added and their life status. The program will update all entries every time it's booted.

In the beginning the application was single-threaded and updating the database entries took 20 seconds (for a list of 50 people). It was way too slow, so I implemented an `ExecutorService` to speed things up by starting API calls concurrently.

My crawler class looks something like this:

```java
    public class Scraper implements Callable<Person> {

        private Person person;

        public Scraper(Person person) {
            this.person = person;
        }

        public synchronized Person scrape() {
            // API call using info from this.person and operations to get the life status
            return new Person(/* with updated parameters */);
        }

        @Override
        public Person call() throws Exception {
            return scrape();
        }
    }
```

The code for updating all entries looks like this:

```java
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    ArrayList<Callable<Person>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

    // people is the HashMap containing tracked people
    people.values().forEach(person -> callables.add(new Scraper(person)));

    try {
        for(Future<Person> f : threadPool.invokeAll(callables)) {
            Person p = f.get();

            // updating old values with p
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // exception handling
        }
        finally {
            threadPool.shutdown();
        }
```

Initially I used `ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`, but almost every time I booted the program some entries got updated the wrong way: some people had other people's page names, so their life status could get mixed up.

Then I switched to `ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);` and now, no matter the number `n` I choose, updating always works flawlessly without conflicts.

Why is that? I learned that `CachedThreadPool`s and `FixedThreadPool`s operate almost in the same way, except `CachedThreadPool` doesn't have a thread limit and might re-use already initialized threads. Although the reusing of threads might be where the problem lies, every `Scraper` object has its own `Person` object, so I don't understand where the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have some `static` fields or maybe `ThreadLocal` values that get mixed up. Maybe a shared HTTP connection  object? Anything like that. But your question doesn't contain enough details to know for sure.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I do have a `static` field, but it's only an integer that keeps track of the number of people that have been updated. Every call to scrape() adds 1 to that static integer.

Comment: There's *probably* a race condition there (it should be an `AtomicInteger`), but I think it's unlikely that that causes the problem you describe.

Comment: @Polcio The problem comes from parts of your code that you have not shown here, so it's a bit hard to guess what the cause could be. Can you try to post a [mcve]?